# MongoDb: Updating objects in one of the many arrays within a document (the array name is not known)

Tags: mongodb, database-design, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Following is a sample document in a collection;

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5414b0ef93f4baa449546bf2"),
    "weekstart" : ISODate("2014-09-07T04:00:00Z"),
    "tuesday" : [ ],
    "wednesday" : [ ],
    "monday" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5414b0ef93f4baa449546bf0"),
            "state" : "pending",
            "label" : "Play",
            "timecreated" : ISODate("2014-09-13T21:02:39Z")
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5414b10793f4baa449546bf3"),
            "state" : "pending",
            "label" : "Watch movie",
            "timecreated" : ISODate("2014-09-13T21:03:03Z")
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5414b11293f4baa449546bf5"),
            "state" : "pending",
            "label" : "Go for walk",
            "timecreated" : ISODate("2014-09-13T21:03:14Z")         
        }
    ],
    "friday" : [ ],
    "saturday" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5414b11293f4baa449546bf7"),
            "state" : "pending",
            "label" : "Do homework",
            "timecreated" : ISODate("2014-09-13T21:03:14Z")         
        }
    ],
    "sunday" : [ ],
    "thursday" : [ ]
}
```

It is required to change a field in an object for which only the '_id' is known but the array in which the object lies is unknown. For example, if the state of the object with id '5414b0ef93f4baa449546bf0' needs to be changed, One way of doing this would be;

```
for(eachName in arrayNames)
{
    db.collection.update({"weekstart" : ISODate("2014-09-07T04:00:00Z"), "eachName._id" : ObjectId("5414b0ef93f4baa449546bf0")}, {"$set" : {"eachName.$.state" : "newState"}})
}
```

However, this way as many queries are required to the database as the number of arrays in the object. I want to do the whole operation in one query. I looked into regular expressions but it turns out that they can be used on the field values and not the field names. Could aggregation or Map-reduce be the answer?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a schema which is not suiting your query and access patterns, and that usually points to the best thing to do is to change it. If you really thing about this, the "day" points such as "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", etc, all all really "data" and therefore should not be the names of "keys" in the document. Keys can only ever be accessed directly by specifying that key name, but data can be fed to a query.

A better way to do this is make the "day" part of the data rather than store different arrays:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5414b0ef93f4baa449546bf2"),
    "weekstart" : ISODate("2014-09-07T04:00:00Z"),
    "data" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5414b0ef93f4baa449546bf0"),
            "day": "monday",
            "state" : "pending",
            "label" : "Play",
            "timecreated" : ISODate("2014-09-13T21:02:39Z")
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5414b10793f4baa449546bf3"),
            "day": "monday",
            "state" : "pending",
            "label" : "Watch movie",
            "timecreated" : ISODate("2014-09-13T21:03:03Z")
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5414b11293f4baa449546bf5"),
            "day": "monday",
            "state" : "pending",
            "label" : "Go for walk",
            "timecreated" : ISODate("2014-09-13T21:03:14Z")         
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5414b11293f4baa449546bf7"),
            "day": "sunday",
            "state" : "pending",
            "label" : "Do homework",
            "timecreated" : ISODate("2014-09-13T21:03:14Z")         
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, when you want to update an element in that "one" array, all you need is the `_id` of the element you seek:

```js
db.collection.update(
    { "data._id": ObjectId("5414b0ef93f4baa449546bf0") },
    { "$set": { "data.$.state" : "newState" } }
)
```

There is no need to "loop" through arrays or anything else since everything is in the one place. In addition, there are other benefits here.

It's still easy to extract a particular "day" from a given item. Just issue the following:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "_id": ObjectId("5414b0ef93f4baa449546bf2"), 
        "data.day": "monday"
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$data" },
    { "$match": { "data.day": "monday" }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "weekstart": { "$first": "$weekstart" },
        "data": { "$push": "$data" }
    }}
])
```

Or even:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "_id": ObjectId("5414b0ef93f4baa449546bf2"), 
        "data.day": "monday"
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "weekstart": 1,
        "data": {
            "$setDifference": [
                { "$map": {
                    "input": "$data",
                    "as": "el",
                    "in": {
                        "$cond": [
                            { "$eq": [ "$$el.day", "monday" ] },
                            "$$el",
                            false
                        ]
                    }
                }},
                [false]
            ]
        }
    }}
])
```

And if you wanted the total counts of "tasks" per each day, then this is quite simple as well:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$data" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$data.day",
        "taskCount": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

The moral of this story is to model your schema based on your access patterns, both how you read it and how you need to update or add new items. When you see a problem, then it usually is a sign that the current data model is wrong and you need to consider something else.

Using "keys" where you should be identifying "data" is never a good pattern, so keep that in mind where designing in order to avoid problems in the future.

Comment: So I have been trying the to push the application layer data structure into mongo as it is, now I get where I was wrong conceptually. Thank you Neil